# where can I see prodcast downloads?

Tags: iphone, podcasts, podcasts.app

I am new with this prodcast application.can anyone please tell me where can I see my downloaded prodcast?Can't I see it in default music app of iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

When you open the podcasts app, you should see all the podcasts you have downloaded. See the image below.

[image]